# Copy/clone SQL Server database schema and some data programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-express

I am developing a point-of-sale Windows Forms application which handling multiple companies. When user creating a new company, I want programmatically clone an existing database with some of the data (some master tables). I am using SQL Server Express and C#.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of copying a database, could you not prepare a backup of an empty database with the data required, then restore that to a new database?

Comment: I want do it programmatically while user creating a new company.

Comment: please explain? One can run an SQL script via code to create a new database, then backup & restore and existing database or restore a preprepared backup. There is no script to copy a database.

Comment: In azure you can copy a database in the portal, which means you may be able to do that programmatically using the Azure API if you want the database in the cloud.